# Create character map image for a font

Tags: image, fonts, character, photoshop, adobe-illustrator

This seemed like the most sensible place to ask this but I'm not sure. What I'd like is an image, a .jpg or a .png or even a .psd, which has the character map of some font I like, and that is 2048x2048.

Comment: This is the wrong place. Stack Overflow is for coding questions. You want http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com.  And to answer your question: http://www.lmnopc.com/bitmapfontbuilder/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Ghoul Fool for the answer: This is the wrong place. Stack Overflow is for coding questions. You want graphicdesign.stackexchange.com. And to answer your question: lmnopc.com/bitmapfontbuilder